# Wait just a moment vs. hold on a minute (before answering a query)

Tags: sentence-construction

Let's say a client is asking a question online, and you put him on hold to confirm your will be answer to your manager, because you want a sure answer before you give it to the inquirer. You say:

> Could you please wait just a moment while I confirm this.

Or

> Could you hold on a minute while I confirm this. (I think this is better)

Which is more ok to say? As I've said, I believe sentence 2 is better than sentence 1.

Answer (score 1):

Both have the same meaning in real life.

A **minute** is very exactly defined scientifically (= 60 seconds), but in this context it means just a little.

The funny story is that "**moment**" was also defined as a unit of measurement of time, long as X seconds and Y fractions of a second. Unfortunately, I do not remember the numbers, since I read about it a very long time ago.

Also, **moment** is nowadays used to be synonymous with "a very short time".

What is even funnier is that colloquially, the following also mean the same thing:

> Please wait a **second**.
>
> Please wait a **minute**.

Comment: While they have the same meaning, "hold on a minute" is notably more casual than "please wait just a moment." The latter is more formal and professional and should be preferred in formal situations.